# How to Specify an alternate panelContext - EasyTabs

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm using the EasyTabs plugin by Alfa Jango on my website, and would like to have the panels seperated from tabs. He states in the documentation what I want to do;

> Your panels can also be somewhere else in the DOM entirely (outside of
>   your tab container), if you specify an alternate panelContext.
>
> The panelContext is any jQuery DOM element, in which easytabs will
>   look for the panels. By default, it's the container on which
>   easytabs() was called.

So, I understand I have to specify panelContext, say, to look for the panels in div#disconnected.

This is what I tried, but nothing works...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#tab-container').easytabs({
            panelContext: '#disconnected';
        });
    });
</script>
```

Or trying to change the $container...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#tab-container').easytabs({
            $container: '#disconnected'  
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem as you, and found the answer:

You should type as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#tab-container').easytabs({
    panelContext: $('div#disconnected')
    });
});
```

Found after looking the code here: [Easy Tabs Github](https://github.com/JangoSteve/jQuery-EasyTabs/issues/129)

Hope it helps